# How to enable Apache as proxy to Docker container?

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, httpd, http-proxy

I need to set up Apache as the web server and have it proxy http requests to a Docker container with its own web server.   I'm starting with the Docker image httpd:2.4.  What modules do I need to enable, and what would my proxy.conf file look like?

Comment: Nevermind I answered my own question.  Enable proxy_module and proxy_http_module, then proxy.conf contains:

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName ubuntu.somesite.com
    <Proxy *>Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://sitecontainer:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://sitecontainer:5000/
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: You should write this as an answer rather than as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable proxy_module and proxy_http_module, then proxy.conf contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  #ServerName ubuntu.somesite.com 
  <Proxy *>
    Allow from all 
  </Proxy> 
  ProxyPass / sitecontainer:5000 
  ProxyPassReverse / sitecontainer:5000 
</VirtualHost>
```